# Sleep Screen in Lock-Screen

Tags: macos

After a macOS update which gave me a moving Landscape Background Image and the Login-Field is now to the bottom of the Screen, I have an issue:

When I leave the Mac I want to Shortcut to Lock Screen and then Press "esc" so that the Screen will turn black/off.

Now that no longer works.

How can I turn the Screen Black/Off after Lock Screen. And what is the new shortcut (Like esc)?

Comment: Pressing escape on the lock screen in Sonoma puts the display to sleep for me (I am using a Macbook).
If you have a keyboard with an eject button you can also press control + shift + eject.

Comment: I don't habe an eject button. In my Version, Version 14.1.1 (23B81) it doesn't work with esc.

Comment: I am using the same version of Sonoma as you. Pressing esc on the lock screen is still working for me. Weird.